# how to backup transmission downloads and torrents?

Tags: system-installation, backup, hard-disk, bittorrent, transmission

How can I backup my torrents to an external hard drive which can be moved from system to system?  I'm using Transmission.

Ideally this would be both complete and incompletely downloaded torrents.  If the `.torrent` files are kept, and their corresponding downloads (all in one folder) then, perhaps, transmission can re-associate?

Or, perhaps, store additional meta-data from transmission associating downloads with torrents?

see also:

https://askubuntu.com/q/1168528/

Answer (score 1):

move `~/.config/transmission` to external drive.

create symbolic link on new system pointing to external drive.

keep in mind that if you unplug drive Transmission would be misbehaving (its config directory would point to non-existent place with no write access).